# Mail is send but at recipt end it says "this mail has no content"

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

Mail is sent using the code below:

```
 {            string from="abcd@gmail.com";
                   using ( MailMessage mail=new MailMessage(from, txtTo. Text) )
          { mail. Subject=txtSubject. Text;
            mail. Body=txtMessage. Text;
            if ( fileUploader. HasFile )
                {
                string fileName=Path. GetFileName(fileUploader. PostedFile. FileName);
                mail. Attachments. Add(new Attachment(fileUploader. PostedFile. InputStream, fileName));
                }
            mail. IsBodyHtml=false;
            SmtpClient smtp=new SmtpClient();
            smtp. Host="smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp. EnableSsl=true;
            NetworkCredential networkCredential=new NetworkCredential();
            networkCredential. UserName="abcd@gmail.com";
            networkCredential. Password="123";
            smtp. UseDefaultCredentials=true;
            smtp. Credentials=networkCredential;
            smtp. Port=587;
            smtp. Send(mail);
            ClientScript. RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Message has been sent successfully.');", true);
            }
```

To compose an email, I have use text area with texeditor added and that formatted text is then allocated to textbox with id `txtmessage` with multiline property. However I get an error saying "This mail has no content"
for above explaination please refer code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfun(){
    var x=document.getElementById("area3").value;
    document.getElementById("txtMessage").inner.HTML=x;  
    }
                    </script>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Along with code you need to provide all data necessary to reproduce the problem - `txtMessage. Text` is not a data that one can see. Ideally you have [MCVE] with all values necessary hardcoded as constants. If you can't - show values outside of the code but still as part of the post by making an [edit] to it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov please have a look, Sir. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

check this line of code:

```
 document.getElementById("txtMessage").inner.HTML=x;
```

Your "txtMessage" should be a `<input>`, then you should just set the `value` of it

```
 document.getElementById("txtMessage").value=x;
```